# Can't exlude directory in CLion if there is `target_include_directories` in CMake

Tags: c++, cmake, clion

In CLion I would like to mark a directory with a library as "Excluded" or "Library Files" so that its contents don't get index by an IDE.

For some reason, this exclusion doesn't work if there is `target_include_directories()` in the root `CMakeLists.txt`. Is this a bug, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Looks like a bug, and probably the best is to submit a ticket to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP with minimal examples to reproduce the issue.